# C data types and memory storage of characters?

Tags: c, memory, types

Hi can anybody solve this exercise from King, this is one thing that I cannot wrap my head around in C. I understand data types in C and their space they are capable of holding. At least I think I did, but for whatever reason I cannot understand the answer to the exercises. This is not some homework request, this is just so I can understand C data types better, and it is something that has plaque me for a while already.Can somebody explain to me the answer and steps involve in getting to them. I have tried many things re-read the chapter search online. I cannot wrap my head around this. Thank you.

Exercise 7.06
For each of the following items of data, specify which one of the types char, short, int, or long is the smallest one guaranteed to be large enough to store the item.

(a) Days in a month

(b) Days in a year

(c) Minutes in a day

(d) Seconds in a day

Solution

(a) Max. 31: char

(b) Max. 366: short

(c) Max. 1500: short

(d) Max. 86760: long

Comment: "King"?  What is that.  Be more explicit - if it is your text book, don't assume everyone who could answer is familiar with it.

Comment: Look into the standard, it defines for each integer data type the minimum range.

Comment: Without familiarity or sight of the text book you refer to, it is hard to see how if you do not understand the explanation therein, you would understand any explanation given here.  Explain precisely what you do not understand.

Comment: Re “Max. 86760”: What planet is this a day on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C implementations may use different widths for their integer types, but the C standard guarantees certain minimums. These are specified in C 2018 5.2.4.2.1 1 (the 2018 C standard, clause 5.2.4.2.1, paragraph 1).

> (a) Days in a month

There are up to 31 days in a month. `char` is guaranteed to store up to at least 127, so it is sufficient.

> (b) Days in a year

There are up to 366 days in a year. That is more than `char` is guaranteed to store, so it is insufficient. `short` is guaranteed to store up to 32,767, so it is sufficient.

> (c) Minutes in a day

There are 60•24 = 1,440 minutes in a regular day, or perhaps 60•25 = 1,500 if there is a transition between Daylight Savings Time and Standard Time that we are including. Again `char` is insufficient and `short` is sufficient.

> (d) Seconds in a day

There are 60•60•24 = 86,400 seconds in a regular day, perhaps 60•60•25 = 90,000 if there is a transition we are including, and one more if there is a leap second, so that gives up to 90,001. That is more than `short` is guaranteed to store, so it is insufficient. `int` is also only guaranteed to store up to 32,767, so it is insufficient. `long` is guaranteed to store up to 2,147,483,647, so it is sufficient.

Comment: This is the solution, thank you. I was approaching this in completely different manner. I assume the minimum data type to store the sentence of characters. Yeah no wonder I could not wrap my head around it. To anyone asking C programming: A modern approach, K.N king. Is an old and pretty common book, it goes into a lot of depth of the language. Again Thank you Eric.

Answer (score 1):

The range of any two'd complement signed *binary* data type is: -2<sup>N-1</sup> to -2<sup>N-1</sup>-1.  Where *N* is bit-width of the data type.

The standard specifies minimum widths for each if these types of 8, 16, 16 and 32 for each if `char`, `short`, `int` and `long` respectively.  Each may be wider, but not wider than the next type in that order, or narrower than the preceding type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Agreed.  Removed that part as unnecessary to the answer and as you say inaccurate.